# Indexing voxels for spherical coordinates

Tags: spherical-coordinates

I am working with voxel volumes which are addressed using spherical coordinates. That is, I operate on voxel elements $V(r, \theta, \phi)$ where $r$ is range, $\theta$ is the azimuth, and $\phi$ is the inclination.
I am however running into issues with the fact that the angular ranges wrap around.

To make the problem a bit easier to follow, let's look at only the azimuth.
The azimuth $\theta$ is defined to lie on the interval $\theta \in [-\pi, \pi]$ and wraps around such that $\theta + 2\pi = \theta$.
I now want to map any azimuth value to a voxel index, which is the same as gridding the data.
My current implementation is to simply map this as

$$
 i(\theta) = v_n \cdot \left\lfloor \frac{\theta - \theta_0}{v_s} \right\rfloor
$$

where $v_n$ is the number of voxels (grid points), $\theta_0$ is the origin such that $i(\theta_0) = 0$, and $v_s$ is the voxel scale (grid size).

This works, but gives a lot of empty voxels in case the data is defined near $\pm \pi$.
For example, if my data range is $\theta \in [-\pi, -\pi + a] \cup [\pi-b, \pi]$ (the same as $[\pi - a, \pi + b]$ before wrapping) then the angular range is $a + b$, but I would have to have voxels created for the entire $2 \pi$ range.

So my question is *how do I best define the mapping between an azimuth angle and its corresponding voxel index?*, with the constraints that

1. I use as few voxels as possible for the data
2. The mapping is invertible so that I can get the spherical coordinate of the voxel center, given its index ($\theta_c(i) = \ldots$)

My only attempt so far is to detect whether the data is best represented by an azimuth range of $[-\pi, \pi]$ or $[0, 2\pi]$, and use two different mappings. But this seems error prone and inelegant.

Comment: Are your voxel cubes of equal size as usual, or cubes in spherical coordinates, i.e. curvilinear cubes arranged in spherical layers ?

Comment: @yves-daost They are a rectangular grid in the spherical coordinates such that each voxel is a cube of size (v_r, v_az, v_inc) with v_r in meters and v_az and v_inc in radians. That is, voxels with larger range correspond to a larger volume in regular cartesian 3d space.

Comment: I don't really see where the difficulty lies. The neighboring cells of a given one have angles with a step increment, positive or negative, and by periodicity of the trigonometric functions, you land at the correct places. The wraparound has no real impact.